# Why is this regex inserting the tag?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following function being called from the MSSQL CLR:

```
private static string ReplaceTags(string input, string TagsReplacementXML)
{
    const string TagNamePattern = @"<\$\w+>";
    const string ReplacementPattern = @"<\${0}\>";

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(TagsReplacementXML);
    var xmltags = doc.Descendants("Tag").Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(x.Attribute("TagName").Value,x.Attribute("TagValue").Value));

    Regex rx = new Regex(TagNamePattern);
    MatchCollection matches;
    matches = rx.Matches(input);
    foreach (Match m in matches)
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, string> tagValues = xmltags.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Format("<${0}>", x.Key) == m.Value);
        if (tagValues.Key != null && tagValues.Value != null)
        {
            input = Regex.Replace(input, string.Format(ReplacementPattern, tagValues.Key), tagValues.Value);
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

I'm passing in

```
<$Content>
```

and something similar to

```
<Root>
  <Tag TagName="Content" TagValue="<some (escaped) HTML with>$0.26</some (escaped) HTML>"/>
</Root>
```

The regex goes and replaces the `<$Content>` with what's in TagValue, but then it goes back and replaces $0 with `<$Content>`, so all the prices that are less than a dollar come out as <$Content>.26

First I'm trying to understand why exactly it's doing that.  I'm somewhat familiar with Regexes, but I'm not aware of anything that would cause it.  The second thing is what can I do to work around it.  I've thought about inserting a `<span/>` in between the $ and 0 so that they're not together, but that is pretty hacky.

Comment: Have you considered escaping the dollar sign?  Either using `\$` or the HTML entity `&#35;` would probably do the job...

Comment: I tried escaping the dollar sign, that didn't work.  Using the HTML entity still doesn't let me just print out the currency using string.Format, but it is a better idea than putting in an empty span for sure.

Comment: @DanPuzey The HTML entity ended up not working because it's encoding the HTML then decoding it (due to it being in the XML).  Ended up going with an HTML comment, though.  Still looking for what behavior causes it.

Comment: The behaviour I believe is that `$0` is the regex escape sequence for inserting the matched string - it's inserting the part of your original string that matches `TagNamePattern` (`<$Content>`).